# XEN VM config locations on Debian Squeeze

Tags: debian, virtual-machines, xen, debian-squeeze

I have inherited a debian squeeze VM host, which is not booting anymore.

I want to export the virtual machines to another host, including config files and disk containers before killing the machine.

Question: Where are the XEN config files for the VMs located on debian squeeze in a standard installation?

(I guess the location of the disk containers will be visible in the configs then)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/var/lib/xend/domains/*/config.sxp for configs where * is some cryptic value

/var/lib/xen/images/ contains the disk images

Answer (score 3):

The configs will be under /etc/xen.  And you are correct - the config files will list the disks/volumes used for each vm.

-- EDIT --

xend-config.sxp is the configuration for your main xen daemon.  It includes configuration for logging, dom0 memory usage, networking between the dom0 and domUs, etc.

If there is an /etc/xen/auto directory, the vm configs may have been placed there.  If not, then you might check /etc/defaults/xendomains to see if a different config path was set there.

If there are no vm configs in the /etc/xen directory, and none in wherever the auto directory is configured to be, then it's very possible that either the configs have been deleted, or this isn't a 'standard' installation.

Comment: Thank you. I have updated my question with some more info regarding /etc/xen. Can you be more specific, where and in what form would I find the several configs. Maybe they have been accidently deleted? Or inside the /etc/xen/xend-config.sxp - or maybe there is still another location that would be mentioned in the xend-config.sxp? Debian tends to move configurations to unexpected places.

Comment: Being most familiar with Debian, I find the configurations are in the  places I expect them to be ;-)